# How do I access a resource from .resx in plain HTML file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resx

I have an MVC application which is localized. This has been easy for me to do from MVC .aspx files like so:

```
h2>@Resources.Resource.IAgreeTo</h2>
```

How do I do this from a plain HTML file that has to exist in the solution as is?

Comment: The only way to do it in an html file would be to user javascript to call a service, is there a reason why you have to use a static HTML file rather than a razor view?

Comment: "How can I change the color of my heading in Notepad?"

Comment: If you have to keep it "as it is" and localized at the same time I recommend you create multiple versions of static html page, every single one localized - like page.en-GB.html, page.en-US.html, etc. Overall this feels like XY problem, can you elaborate more on why you want to do this ?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Well, I guess it has to be an HTML file because its a global error handling page. It doesn't seem worth localizing

Comment: A global error handling page does not have to be a HTML file.